# How can I access the properties of an anonymous object?

Tags: javascript, ajax, anonymous-objects

```
$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" },
  function(data){
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
  });
```

The object `{ name: "John", time: "2pm" }` is anonymous. Normally, I would access the properties of an object using syntax similar to the following:

```
objectname.propertyname
```

But what can I do when there is no `objectname`? How can I access `propertyname`?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  Your object is being passed as data for the POST, while the data parameter you're alerting is whatever's being returned from the server (to specify the format of this, pass an extra type parameter after the function).

Comment: $.post receives a object as parameter with name and time as properties. If I try to write the time, I will have to write the object's name, a dot and the property's name, but there is no object name! Can it go empty? document.write(.time)?

Comment: Like I said, when do you actually need to write the time?  The post function will receive the object and encode it to send to test.php.  Then, you'll get a different object, called data, in return.

Comment: how and where is the object with properties "name" and "time" defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of an anonymous object is that it is just that, anonymous.  It is accessed in context only.  If you want to access the object later on, then you need to assign the object to a variable.

Try:

```
var obj = { name: "John", time: "2pm" };
$.post("test.php", obj,
  function(data){
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    alert("obj name is " + obj.name);
  });
```